# Flexslider carousel / slider not showing - possible conflict?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, flexslider

I inherited an unfinished WordPress development for a client, previous had setup Flexslider with Carousel on this [page](http://109.199.123.244/~gravenhi/road-car/bamford-rose-sports-exhaust-system/) but it is not displaying on the frontend. I have searched and have found this similar [example](http://jsfiddle.net/helgatheviking/Q26g3/), as far as I can see it is setup the same. Flexslider is being called, but checking the console it throws back 'Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function'.

This is the code block in question;

```
            <!-- FlexSlider -->
    <script defer src="http://109.199.123.244/~gravenhi/wp-content/themes/bamfordrose/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
      $('#carousel').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: false,
        animationLoop: false,
        slideshow: false,
        itemWidth: 136,
        itemMargin: 0,
        asNavFor: '#slider'
      });

      $('#slider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: false,
        animationLoop: false,
        slideshow: false,
        sync: "#carousel",
        start: function(slider){
          $('body').removeClass('loading');
        }
      });
    });
    </script>
```

I've also tried WordPress no conflict mode as below, but to no avail.

```
    (function($) {
// Inside of this function, $() will work as an alias for jQuery()
// and other libraries also using $ will not be accessible under this shortcut})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like jQuery is being called twice on the page, once from Google, and once from the local WordPress copy, that will cause unexpected problems.

The flexSlider script is also being called twice, just call it once, load jQuery first and then flexslider.js, and *then* initialise your slider, like this:

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script src='/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js'></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
  $('#carousel').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false,
    itemWidth: 136,
    itemMargin: 0,
    asNavFor: '#slider'
  });
</script>
```

View the source of the page and you'll see the multiple instances of the above scripts, fix those and i think your problem will be eliminated.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it David. I've tried turning off the multiple of calls to FlexSlider and Jquery, but it hasn't changed. It has been setup so it calls Jquery from the wp-includes directory, not something i've seen before. I'm unable to contact or talk to the other dev about this so it's frustrating. I'd usually just enqueue jquery in functions.php and that's it. I'm beginning to think it could possibly be a conflict with another plugin, I will turn them all off individually tomorrow.